# How to create accessible footnotes on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, accessibility

I am trying to create accesible footnotes.
The way I developed them works properly on desktop but not on mobile.

Right now the issue is: VoiceOver goes to the footer section and focus the content of the selected footnote but do not read the content, when the user tries to swipe to read the content, VoiceOver continue reading the content of the next footnote.

This is the structure of the links that will take the user to the proper footnote:

```
<p>Some text<sup><a href="#foot1" role="doc-noteref"><span class="hidden">footnote</span>1</a></sup></p>
```

This is the structure of the footnotes:

```
<p role="doc-footnote" tabindex="-1" id="foot1">
    <sup class="supoffset">
        <span class="ada">HIDDEN TEXT TO THE USER THAT NEEDS TO BE READ BY THE SCREEN READER</span>1</sup>
    <span class="sup-span">VISIBLE TEXT TO THE USER THAT NEEDS TO BE READ BY THE SCREEN READER</span>
</p>
```

This is my JS:

```
$("a[href^='#foot']").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $theFootnote = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top-15}, 400, function() {
        $($theFootnote).focus();
    });
});
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My question is actually very clear, I don't understand why someone downvoted it to close it. If you don't know the answer just ignore the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would check this example on the Web Experience Toolkit (http://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/footnotes/footnotes-en.html), we use it all the time without any issues.

It will flip from footnote to footnote and will allow the user to go back to where they were before activating the footnote link.